# How to access a ListViewDataItem datakeys

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, listview

I am wondering how to access the datakeys of a ListViewDataItem that is a member of a ListView.

What I find strange is that when debugging it is possible to access the DataKeysContainer which can be seen here

[image]

However when attempting to access the DataKeyContainer during coding it is impossible, which can also be seen here

[image]

Any advice on how to access the datakeys and their values for a ListViewDataItem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the second screenshot you have casted to a `ListViewItem`

Comment: @AFriend is correct. change it to `For Each l as ListViewDataItem` and it should work as you require.

Comment: Apologies, silly mistake, however the issue still remains when changed to ListViewDataItem, I am still not able to access the DataKeys - see new and updated second screenshot.

Comment: If you check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.datakeyscontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that the `DataKeysContainer` property is not `Browsable` which is why you can't see it. If you absolutely must use it then you'd have to inherit and make it `Browsable`. You can view the source [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web.Extensions/ui/WebControls/ListViewDataItem.cs)

Comment: @AFriend oh ok i see.. might be better off going down another road so. I am attempting to access the index of the listview where one of its items datakeys contains a certain value. Maybe something similar to the  [ListView.FindItemWithText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext(v=vs.110).aspx) function that is available in windows forms, except in ASP.NET. Any other suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are just trying to access the [Control.DataKeysContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.datakeyscontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which is of type `Control`, correct?

Comment: @djv I am attempting to retrieve the DataKey values for a ListViewDataItem, I am able to access these by working my way through the debugger in a grueling process which starts of by being able to access the ListView.DataKeysContainerProperty, I then proceed to access the DataKeys property of it and then onto the results view and values of the DataKeys, obviously this is not ideal to be going so many layers deep to find values in the debugger however I get the values in the end. These are values that I need to be able to access in my code somehow, however at this stage it is looking unlikely

Comment: @AF14 see my workaround answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use late binding, i.e. box your loop variable in an `Object`. This allows you to defer member validation until when the member is accessed at run-time. It is similar to dynamic in c#.

```
For Each itemObject As Object In lstViewModules.Items
    ' the DataKeysContainer you were looking for
    Dim container = CType(itemObject.DataKeysContainer, Control) 
    ' the same l in your loop
    Dim l = CType(itemObject, ListViewDataItem) 
    '  from here on, the rest of your loop code should work
    Dim key As DataKey = lstViewModules.DataKeys(l.DataItemIndex)
    Dim value = key("name")
Next
```

Since you know it's a `ListView`, you could also cast `container` to `ListView` for design-time ease.

Note: you must have `Option Strict Off` for this to work.

Comment: Thank you very very much, saved me from pulling every last single one of my hairs out

Comment: Just a disclaimer, this is circumventing the original intent of the designer and should be used only when absolutely necessary :)

Comment: oh I see, well its some very useful knowledge to have, after helping me out big time. Once again thanks for your help.